# How to write a multiple query solution as a single query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

My task is to find all those subjects, by their id, that have (at least one, but) the fewest lowest passing grades in the database (the grade being the grade 6). I've managed to write the solution with three queries, however my task is to write it as a single query in MySQL. Thank you in advance.

```
-- 1. single query "solution"
SELECT subject_id FROM (SELECT subject_id, COUNT(*) AS six_count 
FROM exams WHERE grade = 6
GROUP BY subject_id) AS sixes
WHERE subject_id = (SELECT MIN(six_count) FROM sixes);

-- 2. multiple queries solution
CREATE TABLE sixes AS (SELECT subject_id, COUNT(*) AS six_count 
FROM exams WHERE grade = 6
GROUP BY subject_id);

SELECT subject_id FROM sixes
WHERE subject_id = (SELECT MIN(six_count) FROM sixes);

DROP TABLE sixes;
```

**EDIT:**
Exams table example:

```
| subject_id | student_id | exam_year | exam_mark | grade | exam_date  |
|          1 |    20100022|      2011 |     'apr' |    10 | 2011-04-11 |
|          2 |    20100055|      2011 |     'oct' |     6 | 2011-10-04 |
|          3 |    20110030|      2011 |    'jan1' |     7 | 2011-01-26 |
|          5 |    20110055|      2011 |    'jan2' |     6 | 2011-02-13 |
|          5 |    20110001|      2011 |    'jun1' |     8 | 2011-06-23 |
```

Comment: It's not a solution. I get an error that says the "sixes table" does not exist.

Comment: You are more likely to get help if you edit your question to include an example of the data table and your expected output.

Comment: Have you considered putting all this in a single function with multiple outputs? You can also create a stored procedure if it makes sense.

Comment: @NemanjaBeric Just a heads up though, since this looks like homework, both solutions below use kind of a SQL "trick" with the Limit function. This may not have been covered in the course material and might be a bit conspicuous. The pure vanilla SQL approach would require getting the counts of sixes in a subquery, then another subquery outside of that to get the minimum value of that result set, then finally doing the HAVING count(1) = (minimum count from those subqueries)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick. The sub query selects the first lowest number of sixes. The main query selects all subjects with that number. The trick is in `ORDER BY count(*) LIMIT 1`, which makes the sub query return the record with the lowest count.

```
SELECT
  subject_id,
  count(*) as six_count
FROM exams
WHERE grade = 6
GROUP BY subject_id
HAVING count(*) = 
  ( SELECT count(*)
    FROM exams
    WHERE grade = 6
    GROUP BY subject_id
    ORDER BY count(*)
    LIMIT 1
  )
```

Comment: Man... parallel thinking with that first sentence

Comment: Yes, and with the solution too :D

Answer (score 1):

This pattern should do the trick. Generalized names.

```
SELECT subjectID
  FROM TEST_DATA
 WHERE grade = 6
 GROUP
    BY SubjectID
HAVING COUNT(1) = 
         (  SELECT count(1) AS minCount
              FROM TEST_DATA
             WHERE grade = 6
             GROUP 
                BY subjectID
             ORDER
                BY minCount 
             LIMIT 1
         );
```